# Angular.js - How I query the input value in text field to app.value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is what my controller looks like: http://pastebin.com/C7cx9KaQ
and here's the HTML: http://pastebin.com/UEdwasQu

What I want to do is get the value that user types in, in the input field and use that as the value for the app.value (in my controller, please refer to line 7 of the controller)

I tried adding a ng-model to the input text field and then trying to pass that value in app.value but it did not work - assuming that's because its not in the same controller scope

Would be fantastic to learn how I can implement this

Comment: Just a suggestion.. You could have a service responsible for just keeping the value user types. So this service could be used for any controller, as a dependency. I hope I could be clear.

Comment: Thanks :-) makes sense but not sure how that would look code wise, if its okay, would be great to see the code so the context makes sense Cheers :-)